# mobx & react-native issue: ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'AuthStore.modalUrl')

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, mobx

Help required please

Attempting to use mobx in react-native app with versions

```
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-native": "0.65.1",
        "mobx": "6.3.2",
        "mobx-react": "7.2.0",
```

App.js

```
  import { Provider } from "mobx-react";
  import { AuthStore } from './mobx/AuthStore'
  const authStore = new AuthStore()
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>  
    <NavigationContainer>   
      <StripeProvider publishableKey={'...'}>
        <Provider authStore={AuthStore}>
          <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
            <MonitorApp/>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </Provider>
      </StripeProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

AuthStore.js

```
import { observable, action, runInAction } from 'mobx';
class AuthStore {
    @observable urlModal = false;

    @observable provider;
  
    constructor() {
        makeObservable(this)
    }

}
const authStore = new AuthStore()
export default authStore
```

and further down the app in MonitorApp we have a ReactComponent called

```
import {inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';
@inject('authStore') @observer
class MonitorAppOverlay extends React.Component {
    renderModal() {
        const { authStore } = this.props;
        const { modalUrl } = authStore;
        console.log(this.props)
        console.log(AuthStore)
    }
}

export default MonitorAppOverlay
```

modalUrl is undefined and throwing. In a previous version of this app using the same style of using mobx by using @inject the stores were populated without issue

any ideas anyone??

UPDATED with correct constructors in store and all working now

Answer (score 1):

Right now you just passing store constructor to `Provider`, but you need to create instance of your `AuthStore` first, and pass this instance to provider.